# Swagger Angular client complains about missing HTTPClientModule even though it is being imported

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger-codegen

I generated a TypeScript/Angular client for my backend's REST API using Swagger Codegen and am trying to use it in my Angular project. Following the README file Swagger generated, I `yarn link`ed the client's `dist/` folder into my project's `node_modules` and updated my `app.module.ts` like so:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; // <-- Added this line

import { ApiModule } from '@my-project/rest-client'; // <-- and this one

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule, // <-- and these
    ApiModule // <---------- two lines
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The result:

> Error: You need to import the HttpClientModule in your AppModule!  See
>   also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575

What gives?! I'm at a complete loss as to what I'm doing wrong and would highly appreciate any help. FYI, I also created a fresh Angular project using `ng new`, with the only change being the addition of the above lines to `app.module.ts` and the results turned out to be the same. I am using:

- Angular 5.2.10 (for both my project and the generated client)
- Angular CLI 1.7.4
- [This snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.0-20180416.050135-228.jar) of the upcoming Swagger Codegen 2.4.0
- TypeScript 2.5.3 (in my project) and 2.8.3 (in the generated client)

Could this issue possibly be related to the difference in TypeScript versions between my project and the client? I find it somewhat odd that Swagger Codegen doesn't fix the TypeScript version to be precisely the same version that Angular 5.2.10 uses but, instead, ends up using TypeScript 2.8.3.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to update your application to TypeScript 2.8.3 to see if that solves the issue?

Comment: Try to run a npm update

Comment: Thank you for your comments! The problem is that the `package.json` Angular generated for my project enforces Typescript `~2.5.3`. So I just replaced this with `^2.5.3` and ran `yarn install`. But now `ng serve` is warning me that `@angular/compiler-cli@5.2.10 requires typescript@'>=2.4.2 <2.7.0' but 2.8.3 was found instead. Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.` ([explanation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7625#issuecomment-328174683)), though it keeps running – however, I'm still seeing the same error from the Swagger client.